# Switching PictureBox Images C#

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I'm trying to make a "checkbox" that has a custom check image. I need it to toggle between checked and unchecked when the user clicks the picturebox. I've tried the following code, and the first click shows the checked image fine, however a second click does nothing. Any ideas?

```
    private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox7.Image == Image.FromFile(checkedImg))
        {
            pictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile(uncheckedImg);
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile(checkedImg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statement is wrong as it is unlikely to return `true` because you are comparing instances of the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class which you recreate every time. You could modify it like this:

```
private bool _pbChecked = false;
private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    string imgPath = _pbChecked ? uncheckedImg : checkedImg;
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
    _pbChecked = !_pbChecked;
}
```